# Update username on WSO2-IS with a JDBC user store

Tags: jdbc, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm using Identity Server 5.1.0 with a JDBC user store.

I have followed https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Using+Email+Address+as+the+Username to allow the emails being the username.

I have a requirement to the change of the user's email address and i'm thinking either I can :

1. use some config to allow updating the username attribute
2. use other (mutable) attribute for authentication.

As of now im getting the follwoing exception for updating the user name attribute:

```
User name is immutable in carbon user store
```

How can i go about this?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Changing user name is not supported for JDBC user stores OOTB.

But you can write a custom user store manger to handle it. Make sure you change all the places when you do this operation, since some tables (Ex: IDN_USER_ACCOUNT_ASSOCIATION table) keeps user name as a key.

Answer (score 0):

A working sample for this is available in [1] with the details. You can write a custom JDBC user store manager and get this done.

[1] http://tharindue.blogspot.com/2015/05/a-workaround-for-renaming-username-of.html